What is the utility of a "clock'event" if the sensitivity list has a single signal and is tested at 1?
I was wondering what is the difference between
process (clk)
if (clk = '1') then

and
process (clk)
if (clk'event and clk = '1') then

I thought the sensitivity list defined on which signals a state change would be monitored so if I am right then the clk'event is redundant.
I have made a simple simulation to verify what I thought and it apparently confirmed my opinion.

Provide an [mcve] or at least complete process statements here. Both IEEE Std 1076 and 1076.6-2004 RTL Synthesis (withdrawn) require any signals evaluated to be in process sensitivity list. Leaving those out for inferred latches results in a simulation and synthesized hardware behavior mismatch which can be overcome by specifying the use of an edge event evaluation for edge sensitive storage or by adding other evaluated signals when inferring level sensitive storage. Your behavioral description is incomplete and from your narrative, defective.

Yes, you are right, during a simulation both code snippets work identically.
But during synthesis all signals which are read in the process are added implicitly to the sensitivity list.
This means if there is the assignment B<=A; inside the process, A is added to the sensitivity list and at
any time when A is changed B will also change, if clk='1'.
So without clk'event the code describes a latch and not a flipflop in synthesis.

Wouldn't that be a bug in the synthesis tool?

The question is not about synthesis. There is no standard for how synthesis tools interpret VHDL code to infer primitives - it has simply become "the norm" that all tools mostly ignore sensitivity lists - but I have seen instances where a change in sensitivity lists affects the logic that is inferred.

Nevertheless the now withdrawn RTL Synthesis standard is the basis for every synthesis tool distinguishing between edge and level sensitive storage and the 1076 standard requires any signals being evaluated appear in a process sensitivity list, including equivalent process statements for concurrent signal assignment statements distinguishing the two.

There is no difference in the two posted snippets. Using the 'event attribute can be used to determine which signal has had an event in a process with multiple signals in the sensitivity list.
For example:
process(a, b)
begin
  if a = '1' then
    -- do something here

in this case, the if branch is entered when a or b changes, so if you only want to enter the branch when a changes, the check on a'event is also required:
process(a, b)
begin
  if a'event and a = '1' then
    -- do something here only when a changes to '1'

